# Python Zeep : How to get get / retrieve header info : charset

Tags: python-3.x, zeep

I tried to understand how to get / retrieve header information charset with transport.get but I do not know what parameters are to be passed ...

I want to know the charset to perform the encoding before sending the data : utf-8, iso-1559, ...

```
session         = Session()
session.auth    = HTTPBasicAuth("user","passwd")
session.proxies = {'http': "http://my_ip:my_port"}

url             = "http://my_url?wsdl"
transport       = Transport(session=session)   
client          = Client(wsdl=url,transport=transport)
encode          = client.transport.get (url, , Message=???, Headers=???)
```

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

with ipython I looked at the attributes and the solution that I found this solution

```
headers         = {}
response        = client.wsdl.transport.get(url, None, headers)
encode          = response.encoding
```